# Unexpected token `tag` expected in pug

Tags: pug, keystone

I am working with pug in keystone and while adding side navigation i am getting error like this.

```
> 6| a(href="#")About
--------------------^
7| a(href="#")Services
8| a(href="#")Client
9| a(href="#")Contact

Unexpected token `tag` expected `text`, `interpolated-code`, `code`, `:`, `slash`, `newline` or `eos`
```

Comment: Can you please show us the complete pug template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There needs to be a space between the tag/attributes and its content (after the closing parentheses) in order for it to be valid Pug:

```
a(href='#') About
```

More examples in the documentation on using [tags with attributes in Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html)